# Likelihood optimization with respect to a diagonal matrix

Tags: r, optimization

I have a problem with the **optim()** function. I have a log-likelihood function, derived from the VAR process, with a lot of parameters. I want to optimize it with respect to the parameter Φ which is a diagonal matrix (so this is variation of the VAR). V is a full matrix.

```html
<a href="http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=\begin{align*}l[V,&space;\Phi&space;|\kappa_{(t)}]&=&space;-\frac{n(T-1)}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{T-1}{2}\log(|V|)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=2}^{T}\left[(\kappa_{(t)}-\Phi\kappa_{(t-1)})^{tr}&space;V^{-1}(\kappa_{(t)}-\Phi\kappa_{(t-1)})\right]&space;\end{align*}" target="_blank"><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\begin{align*}l[V,&space;\Phi&space;|\kappa_{(t)}]&=&space;-\frac{n(T-1)}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{T-1}{2}\log(|V|)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=2}^{T}\left[(\kappa_{(t)}-\Phi\kappa_{(t-1)})^{tr}&space;V^{-1}(\kappa_{(t)}-\Phi\kappa_{(t-1)})\right]&space;\end{align*}" title="\begin{align*}l[V, \Phi |\kappa_{(t)}]&= -\frac{n(T-1)}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{T-1}{2}\log(|V|)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=2}^{T}\left[(\kappa_{(t)}-\Phi\kappa_{(t-1)})^{tr} V^{-1}(\kappa_{(t)}-\Phi\kappa_{(t-1)})\right] \end{align*}" /></a>
```

I have tried to optimize it using the function:

fr <- function(n,T,V,kappa_data,Phi_diag) {

Vinv=solve(V)

Phi=diag(Phi_diag)

result=-n*(T-1)/2*log(2*pi)-(T-1)/2*log(det(V))

```
for(t in 1:(T-1)){

  kappa_t=kappa_data[(t+1),]
  kappa_tm1=kappa_data[t,]
  l=t(kappa_t-Phi%*%t(kappa_tm1))
  r=(kappa_t-Phi%*%t(kappa_tm1))
  z=t(as.numeric(l))%*%Vinv%*%as.numeric(r)

  result=result+z
  }
```

return(result)
}

but I am not sure how to optimize it and is this the right function to use..

Comment: I am not even sure if this is a programming related question. Can you elaborate on what you use and which `optim()` function you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I fixed it.. i use the optin() function: optim(rep(1,6),fr,method=("CG")) and it converges nicely estimating  the diagonal of Phi.. :)

Comment: Maybe you could at least at which programming language and/or framework this is about.

Comment: mhm... sorry i thought this is forum only for R users... the platform is R

Comment: No need to say sorry, but work your way through the help and about pages. When asking the right questions and honoring what the help pages tell you, ppl will be glad to help you out :)